# Can anyone identify the microcontroller on a W1209 thermostat?

Tags: microcontroller, identification

Can anyone identify the micro-controller on a W1209 thermostat board?

The W1209 is a simple very cheap relay thermostat that used to come with TM8S003F3P6 or another unmarked micro-controller in TSSOP20 casing. On this board I recently purchased from Aliexpress the micro-controller is in QFN24 casing and the LDO on the board is now changed to AMS1117-3.3 (instead of the HT7150 on my previous boards) which means it works on 3.3V.

The marking on the board is 808D G00FZ 1617+.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the point? You're very unlikely to be able to extract the program from it.

Comment: @Transistor https://github.com/TG9541/stm8ef/wiki/Board-W1209

Comment: I have a very similar variant... it looks just like yours, and that chip says `808D G00... 16...+`. And I'm troubleshooting a problem with a freezer where it says LLL when it hits 0 (so can't go below 0 unless I move the sensor somewhere warmer than 0 until the freezer is way below 0). And it seemingly randomly fails when it's happily at -25°C for a while, eventually saying HHH or LLL...sometimes with rapid clicking relay sounds.

Comment: @Peter I had a similar problem (HHH/LLL) with another W1209 with the previous unmarked micro-controller so I suspect it is rather a software problem. I solved it by resetting the device to default values ([long pressing the + & -](https://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?t=1900) and than setting the parameters (I skipped changing P2 & P3 this time) and it worked for me.

Comment: Quite possibly a similar chip in a different package, with some N.C. leads (I see only 20 connected on your PCB). The lack of logo may point to it being a clone of some kind. I doubt it would be worth their while porting the code to another MCU.

Answer (score 2):

This is EFM8SB20F16G-A. Just read and verified it in the same timer.

Comment: I've checked the [datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/EFM8SB2-DataSheet.pdf). The marking on the IC doesn't seem to quite match the QFN24 package marking on page 46.

Comment: I have read, erased and written this controller in the same timer. Works great. Dev ID corresponds to the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

The processor seems to be an ES7P003.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help. Can you add more explanation, please? There is already an answer reporting that it's a different MCU, so people will be curious how/why you identified that specific device. You can [edit] your answer to add supporting information & details. Thanks. (Also, as you are new here, please read the [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules and etiquette. Again, thanks.)

Answer (score -3):

The W1209 thermostat module has a STM8S controller

Comment: Please explain how you know this (i.e. cite a source which confirms it).

Comment: Most of the old W1209s do have STM8S but the microcontroller on this board is not STM8S.

Comment: I agree, this is not the STM8S that I quickly concluded from the W1209 wiki page. None of the STM8S come in QFN24 packages, so it cannot be this part.

Comment: The ATtiny42x and ATtiny82x are a good candidate, but depends on where the VCC and GND pins land. The OP should post which pins get VCC and GND to assist.